# Is it possible to modify an existing TensorFlow computation graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

TensorFlow graph is usually built gradually from inputs to outputs, and then executed. Looking at the Python code, the inputs lists of operations are immutable which suggests that the inputs should not be modified. Does that mean that there is no way to update/modify an existing graph?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The TensorFlow [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph) class is an *append-only* data structure, which means that you can add nodes to the graph after executing part of the graph, but you cannot remove or modify existing nodes. Since TensorFlow executes only the necessary subgraph when you call [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run), there is no execution-time cost to having redundant nodes in the graph (although they will continue to consume memory).

To remove *all* nodes in the graph, you can create a session with a new graph:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():  # Create a new graph, and make it the default.
  with tf.Session() as sess:  # `sess` will use the new, currently empty, graph.
    # Build graph and execute nodes in here.
```

Comment: "although they will continue to consume memory" - is this memory released when the session is garbage collected by the python runtime?

Comment: Variable data (e.g. the weights of a neural network for example) would be released with the session, this is where the bulk of your memory will be, but the graph definitions (the actual operation definitions, which don't contain data) will stay with the Graph object until it is released or the graph is reset. This becomes an issue only if you continue appending new graph operations, which is generally bad practice. A good rule to follow is never create graph operations after your session is open, if you do so you're more likely than not doing something wrong. TF 2.0 changes all of this.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, `tf.Graph` are build in an append-only fashion as @mrry puts it.

**But there's workaround**:

Conceptually you can modify an existing graph by cloning it and perform the modifications needed along the way. As of r1.1, Tensorflow provides a module named `tf.contrib.graph_editor` which implements the above idea as a set of convinient functions.

Comment: Too bad the documentation is poor regarding these methods

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what @zaxily and @mrry says, I want to provide an example of how to actually do a modification to the graph. In short:

1. one can not modify existing operations, all ops are final and non-mutable
2. one may copy an op, modify it's inputs or attributes and add new op back to the graph
3. all downstream ops that depend on the new/copied op have to be recreated. Yes, a signifficant portion of the graph would be copied copied, which is not a problem

The code:

```
import tensorflow
import copy
import tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor as ge
from copy import deepcopy

a = tf.constant(1)
b = tf.constant(2)
c = a+b

def modify(t): 
    # illustrate operation copy&modification
    new_t = deepcopy(t.op.node_def)
    new_t.name = new_t.name+"_but_awesome"
    new_t = tf.Operation(new_t, tf.get_default_graph())
    # we got a tensor, let's return a tensor
    return new_t.outputs[0]

def update_existing(target, updated):
    # illustrate how to use new op
    related_ops = ge.get_backward_walk_ops(target, stop_at_ts=updated.keys(), inclusive=True)
    new_ops, mapping = ge.copy_with_input_replacements(related_ops, updated)
    new_op = mapping._transformed_ops[target.op]
    return new_op.outputs[0]

new_a = modify(a)
new_b = modify(b)
injection = new_a+39 # illustrate how to add another op to the graph
new_c = update_existing(c, {a:injection, b:new_b})

with tf.Session():
    print(c.eval()) # -> 3
    print(new_c.eval()) # -> 42
```

Comment: Is there a way to perform the same operation with tensorflow 2.3 using the graph from a tf.function?

Answer (score 0):

For tensorflow v>=2.6, using Graph directly [have been depcreated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#attributes)

> A tf.Graph can be constructed and used directly without a tf.function, as was required in TensorFlow 1, but this is **deprecated** and it is recommended to use a tf.function instead. If a graph is directly used, other deprecated TensorFlow 1 classes are also required to execute the graph, such as a tf.compat.v1.Session.

That being said, I think your question can be still relevant, I think the kind of problem you are facing might be solved when using [tensorflow eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager). While running  tf in eager mode, you can run, modify the graph before building it test it before building it...

> TensorFlow's eager execution is an imperative programming environment that evaluates operations immediately, without building graphs: operations return concrete values instead of constructing a computational graph to run later. This makes it easy to get started with TensorFlow and debug models, and it reduces boilerplate as well. To follow along with this guide, run the code samples below in an interactive python interpreter.

However be careful eager mode trade **debugging/flexbillity** with **performance/speed**, so for production you might consider turning it off.

Lastly, there is other feature of tensorflow, that might be relvant for this probelm, which is [tensor slicing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor_slicing), `tf.slice`.