# Rebuilding the Graph while keeping the variables

Tags: tensorflow

I have variables that change size over the course of the program, and variables that should get added into the middle of the Graph, but when I run the program, those variables remain unchanged.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235225/is-it-possible-to-modify-an-existing-tensorflow-computation-graph) which tells me it's not possible to change variables after the Graph has been created, and suggests a method of creating a session with a new graph.  When I tried that, I got issues with having uninitialized Variables.  I tried saving the variables I needed and then restoring them in the new Session, but it still claimed they were uninitialized.

How can I add Variables to a Session while keeping their previous values?  Or, better if possible, how can I change the size of Variables in a Graph, or force the Graph to restructure without reinitializing the Variables?

Comment: You could save values of TensorFlow variables to python variables, and then use those Python values to initialize your variables when building new graph

Comment: I can't access the TensorFlow values, that's been one of the big things making progress slow from the start.  The Variables I need are weight and bias matrices, but I can't just grab the values.

Comment: do "(x,y) = sess.run([varx, vary]); .... make new session/graph....varx=tf.Variable(x); sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())"