# In Tensorflow, how can I rename a certain operation name?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I think this question may sound weird. Let's say, there is a tensor `a`.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2400], name="x")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2400], name="y")
a = tf.add(x, y, name="a")
```

Is there an efficient way to refer `a` with a different name, like `out`?
I am thinking a dummy operation like

```
b = tf.add(a, 0, name="out")
```

I am asking this because I am trying different network architectures, and regardless of architectures, I would like to access the output tensor with a consistent name like

```
tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("out:0")`
```

For now, output tensors are depending on architectures like `fc1/fc1wb:0` or `fc2/fc2wb:0`. How can I wrap the final op with a certain name?

Comment: You can use `tf.identity` to make a copy of a tensor and `graph_editor.reroute_a2b_ts` to connect it to consumers of previous tensor

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov  I see that using tf.identity changes the type from a variable to a tensor type -- would that affect a model in anyway?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34235413/2542516) answer suggests that `tf.Graph` is append only, you cannot modify it.

That being said, a slightly better way to rename a tensor is to use [tf.identity](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity) like this:

```
tf.identity(a, name="out")
```

EDIT: After figuring out answer to one of my own questions, I can see a slightly better way to do this:

```
graph_def.node[<index of the op you want to change>].name = "out"
```

the `index` is usually `-1` because final output tensors are in the end of the `graph_def`

Comment: Changing `graph_def.node[index].name` does not work. If this node is input to any other node, such a reference is by name, so you need to update those as well.

Comment: To update the references to your renamed node, loop through `graph.node` and for each such node through `node.input`. If `node.input[2]` is your renamed node, you can replace `node.input[2] = new_name`.