# Unable to load a pretrained model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, chatbot

After training my model for almost 2 days 3 files were generated:

```
best_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
best_model.ckpt.index
best_model.ckpt.meta
```

where `best_model` is my model name.
When I try to import my model using the following command

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('best_model.ckpt.meta')
  saver.restore(sess, "best_model.ckpt")
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "/home/shreyash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1577, in 
import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/shreyash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 498, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)

File "/home/shreyash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 259, in import_graph_def
    raise ValueError('No op named %s in defined operations.' % node.op)

ValueError: No op named attn_add_fun_f32f32f32 in defined operations.
```

How to fix this?

I have referred this post: [TensorFlow, why there are 3 files after saving the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265035/tensorflow-why-there-are-3-files-after-saving-the-model)

- Tensorflow version 1.0.0 installed using pip
- Linux version 16.04
- python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The importer can't find a very specific function in your graph, namely `attn_add_fun_f32f32f32`, which is likely to be [one of attention functions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/attention_decoder_fn.py#L407).

Probably you've stepped into [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8433). However, they say it's bundled in tensorflow 1.0. Double check that installed tensorflow version contains `attention_decoder_fn.py` (or, if you are using another library, check that it's there).

If it's there, here are your options:

- [Rename this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819397/in-tensorflow-how-can-i-rename-a-certain-operation-name), if possible. You might want to read [this discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4757) for workarounds.
- Duplicate your graph definition, so that you won't have to call `import_meta_graph`, but restore the model into the current graph.