# tensorflow how to change dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Dataset API doohickey which is part of my tensorflow graph.  How do I swap it out when I want to use different data?

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

variable = tf.Variable(3, dtype=tf.int64)
model = variable*next_element

#pretend like this is me training my model, or something
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(variable.initializer)
    try:
        while True:
            print(sess.run(model)) # (0,3,6)
    except:
        pass

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(2)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()  

### HOW TO DO THIS THING?
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(variable.initializer) #This would be a saver restore operation, normally...
    try:
        while True:
            print(sess.run(model)) # (0,3)... hopefully
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible.  You are asking to change the computation graph itself, which is not allowed in tensorflow.  Rather than explain that myself, I find the accepted answer in this post to be particularly clear in explaining that point [Is it possible to modify an existing TensorFlow computation graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235225/is-it-possible-to-modify-an-existing-tensorflow-computation-graph)

Now, that said, I think there is a fairly simple/clean way to accomplish what you seek.  Essentially, you want to reset the graph and rebuild the `Dataset` part.  Of course you want to reuse the `model` part of the code.  Thus just put that model in a class or function to allow reuse.  A simple example built on your code:

```
# the part of the graph you want to reuse
def get_model(next_element):
    variable = tf.Variable(3,dtype=tf.int64)
    return variable*next_element

# the first graph you want to build
tf.reset_default_graph()

# the part of the graph you don't want to reuse
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

# reusable part
model = get_model(next_element)

#pretend like this is me training my model, or something
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    try:
        while True:
            print(sess.run(model)) # (0,3,6)
    except:
        pass

# now the second graph
tf.reset_default_graph()

# the part of the graph you don't want to reuse
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(2)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()  

# reusable part
model = get_model(next_element)

### HOW TO DO THIS THING?
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    try:
        while True:
            print(sess.run(model)) # (0,3)... hopefully
    except:
        pass
```

**Final Note**: you will also see some references here and there to `tf.contrib.graph_editor` [docs here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor). They specifically say that you can't accomplish exactly what you want with the graph_editor (see in that link: "Here is an example of what you cannot do"; but you can get pretty close).  Even still though, it's not good practice; they had good reason to make the graph append only, and I think the above method I suggest is the cleaner way to accomplish what you seek.

Comment: This is what I've been doing, and it is working.  When I asked the question, I was having problems restoring the variables because I wasn't resetting the default graph (duh!).  This is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One way I would suggest but that will make things slower is by using `place_holders` followed by the `tf.data.dataset`. Therefore, you will have the following:

```
train_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, None, 1]) # just an example
# Then add the tf.data.dataset here
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data).shuffle(10000).batch(batch_size)
```

Now when running the graph within a session, you have to feed in the data using the placeholder. So you feed whatever you like...

Hope this helps!!